# How to package a PHP application\script?

Tags: php, curl, package

I have a script that uses php and curl to auto logon to a site and perform some actions. 
That bit is ok but I now want to send the script to other people so they can use it.

So I can create a batch file that executes the script.

The problem will be the users won't have php instaled on their computer and would probally have to enable curl in the php.ini file too.

To ask the user to perform all these actions would be messy. Is there anyway I could create a basic instalation or something like that, that would package the whole thing toghether?

Thanks for any answers :-)

Comment: If your target user doesn't have php installed, then php may not be a good choice for your script.

Comment: *wishes there was a way to "compile" PHP into an executable*

Comment: Are all of your users using the same OS? If so, which one? If not, are you willing to support multiple packages for your software? If your users don't have PHP installed, will they be OK with you installing it for them? Ditto for curl.

Answer (score 1):

There's [phc -- the open-source PHP compiler](http://www.phpcompiler.org/).

On another note, are you sure your users will have curl installed? And if not, and you decide to distribute it with your app, will they have all curl's dependencies installed?

Answer (score 0):

Found this googling http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's overdoing things but you can 
look into Titanium Desktop
http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/

Its Open Source, Cross Plataform and free. It basically lets you create a desktop application with web app technologies ( sort of like Adobe Air), and it has support for php scripts. This will of course mean that you have to create an User Interface with at least a button to run your script.